# Check if EditText is empty in real time

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

In one activity of my app I have 5 EditText fields. However, I want `etPlayer5` only to be enabled when the other 4 EditTexts are not empty. I wrote this little code to achieve this:

```
    etPlayer1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPlayer1);
    etPlayer2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPlayer2);
    etPlayer3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPlayer3);
    etPlayer4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPlayer4);
    etPlayer5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPlayer5);

    if (namePlayer1.matches("")||namePlayer2.matches("")||namePlayer3.matches("")||namePlayer4.matches("")) {
        etPlayer5.setEnabled(false);
        etPlayer5.setFocusable(false);
    }
    else {
        etPlayer5.setEnabled(true);
        etPlayer5.setFocusable(true);
    }
```

Of course this code doesn't work in real time. What do I need to do that when the last of the EditTexts 1 to 4 is filled in, `etPlayer5` is automatically set enabled without using a button or something?

Thank you!

Comment: can you at least tell me what's wrong with my question when you downvote it? My specific problem has not been answered anywhere else.

Comment: I also don't know why this was downvoted. I think you are victomised by hit and run case :) I am upvoting it

Comment: I have written a sample code check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have textChangeListener with all 4 Edittexts and keep boolean against all edittext. Update booleans to true when you get call of onTextChange and see if the string length is one in this edittext and further check remaining booleans are also true.This is the trick. Now this is the time to make the edittext enable.Hope that helps.Below is the code for above explanation

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText et1, et2, et3, et4, et5;
boolean firsEditText, secondEditText, thirdEditText,  fourthEditText, fifthEditText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
    et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
    et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et3);
    et4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et4);
    et5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et5);

    et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().length() > 0) {
                firsEditText = true;
                if (checkAllTrue())
                    et5.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                firsEditText = false;
                et5.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    et2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().length() > 0) {
                secondEditText = true;
                if (checkAllTrue())
                    et5.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                secondEditText = false;
                et5.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    et3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().length() > 0) {
                thirdEditText = true;
                if (checkAllTrue())
                    et5.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                thirdEditText = false;
                et5.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    et4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().length() > 0) {
                fourthEditText = true;
                if (checkAllTrue())
                    et5.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                fourthEditText = false;
                et5.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });


}

private boolean checkAllTrue() {
    if (firsEditText && secondEditText && thirdEditText && fourthEditText)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Great, thank you! I also added the line et5.setEnabled(false); to the onCreate method so that it is disabled by default.

Comment: @newman you can do the same thing xml as well rather adding one more line of code in your activity ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    boolean player1Changed = false, player2Changed = false;

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    etPlayer1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPlayer1);
    etPlayer2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPlayer2);
    etPlayer5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPlayer5);

    etPlayer1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        // you can call or do what you want with your EditText here
        player1Changed = true;

        if(player1Changed && player2Changed){
           etPlayer5.setEnabled(true);
           etPlayer5.setFocusable(true);
        }

      }

      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
   });
}

etPlayer2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        // you can call or do what you want with your EditText here
        player2Changed = true;

        if(player1Changed && player2Changed){
           etPlayer5.setEnabled(true);
           etPlayer5.setFocusable(true);
        }

      }

      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
   });
}
}
```